# Is is possible to access folder view in local host using header in php?

Tags: php

I'm looking to use this as a form of security for hosting files off my computer. I was wondering if I am able to use the header function in php to go back to folder view in localhost, or if i can only go to other files with it.

```
if(ISSET($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['pass']=="password"){
        header("Location:\Other");
    }
}
```

Comment: Go back a folder? You mean `../` ?

Comment: no, not go back a folder, but view a subfolder in folder view, rather than link to a file

Comment: You mean if you have /abcd as a directory, and /abcd contains /efgh as another directory, then when user visits /abcd, he/she should be shown the directory listing of /efgh?

Comment: exactly. I'm trying to put a very simple password protection on a subfolder, so when they click on /abcd it opens a php file asking for a password, and if they put the right password in, it allows them to view /efgh

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

function dirToArray($dir) { 

   $result = array(); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $result[] = $value; 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   return $result; 
}

if(!empty($_POST)) {
   if($_POST['password'] == 'yoursecretpassword') {
      $dir    = './efgh';
      print_r(dirToArray($dir));
   }
}
?>

<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It gives me this error when i try to use that:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /_Files_/Other/< on this server.

Comment: Do you get to that password screen or even before that it throws this error?

Comment: it displays the form, but as soon as you submit, the error pops up

Comment: Make sure you do not redirect the user anywhere. I mean store this file as /abcd/index.php and the form action should also point to this file. You don't need to redirect user to /Other folder. It'll automatically fetch that (change ./efgh to ./Other)

Answer (score 0):

This is my entire php document:

```
function dirToArray($dir) { 

   $result = array(); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $result[] = $value; 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   return $result; 
}

if(!empty($_POST)) {
   if($_POST['password'] == 'password') {
      $dir    = './Other';
      print_r(dirToArray($dir));
   }
}
?>

<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my folder structure:

- Files
- Other  - index.php
- Folders/Items I wish to view

It now gives me this error:

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /Files/< on this server.